# How can I debug this PHP Syntax Error message?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, syntax-error

**FINAL UPDATE: I have taken a copy of a "php.ini" from a working server, edited it to match my existing settings and removed the old file, and I have seen no further errors for an hour or more, so I assume that this is RESOLVED.  I can only assume that there was some sort of corruption to the old php.ini file.**

UPDATED: I am seeing MANY of these error messages in my apache2 error.log:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 7
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 7
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 7
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 7
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 7
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 7
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 8
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 46
```

Version is: PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

I have reviewed my php.ini file, and I see nothing that might be causing this.

**Any assistance in debugging this would be HIGHLY appreciated.**

ADDING SOME OTHER DETAILS I AM OBSERVING:
Since I first posted this question, I have noticed that AFTER I made the edits as suggested to test to see if that specific "php.ini" file changes behavior as expected (I deleted the comment on line 46), I re-edited the file to remove my edits, and restarted apache, but the errors resulting from my modified line 46 are continuing to be logged in error.log -- is it being cached somewhere that I need to flush out or something ?  Also notice that the errors are cyclical.  Same sequence of errors each time...

Comment: OK - so I acknowledge that this is a duplicate of the other one mentioned above, but I do not see any answer in that one, nor can I COMMENT about it because I have insufficient "Points" to do so...  So I am left with little wiggle room here.  Note that, as suggested by @ndasusers, I edited my php.ini file, on line 46 (deleted the comment on the line) and the errors began for that line also.  So I AM using that particular "php.ini" file, the commented lines ARE counted correctly in the error message output, and I remain baffled by this issue...

Comment: I asked a question on Meta about this, and why it is marked incorrectly, and hopefully they will change it.

Comment: Thanks - that is a good question to ask.  I don't want to get beaten up about this, and the behavior is very strange...  I will edit the original question to add some new details that I am finding too, and to delete some irrelevant detail.

Comment: That's always the best way to go.

Comment: @MarkBaker Did you have a solution in mind? The OP (as stated above) says that the dupe question does not answer his, and there's no answer to the other question anyway.